# Как через python отправить request?

Tags: python, request

У меня есть вот это `curl -X POST https://trace.moe/api/search -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "image" : "'$(base64 -w 0 your_search_image.jpg)'" }'`
Как это можно отправить через python?

Comment: Есть библиотека requests.

Comment: А как это можно воплотить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На Python3 можно примерно вот так

```
import requests


data = {
  "image": 'Твоё изображение'
}
url = 'https://trace.moe/api/search'
response = requests.post(url, json=data)
print (response.json())
```

Comment: Кст, раз просите requests отправить json, то он сам добавит заголовок `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`, так что `headers` необязательно тут

Comment: @gil9red исправил, спасибо

Comment: А как изображение в base64 передать?

Comment: @likupi base64.encodestring(open(img_file,"rb").read())

Comment: А как это интегрировать в код в ответе.

Comment: @likupi Если API к которому ты обращаешься действительно в параметре `image` принимает на вход base64, тогда можешь сделать так
`image = base64.encodestring(open('путь к твоему изображению',"rb").read())`
и в `data` - `image` передать эту переменную.

Comment: Ошибку выводит https://i.imgur.com/RXvFxu6.png

Comment: @likupi вам нужно скачать изображение и указать локальный путь к ней.

Comment: Всё равно не работает

Comment: @likupi какая ошибка?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/TLr1GKq.png

Comment: @likupi попробуйте просто открыть кодом это изображение, ошибка в строке где путь передаёте. Например через 'os' модуль проверить существование файла.

Comment: А как это сделать?